# How to save multidimensional array in custom class with settings

Tags: c#, class, serialization, save, settings

I have a class which i wish to save instances of within my settings file. I am unable to save the class using the regular properties.settings.default.save() command. No error will come up, but the settings will not persist between runs, which i understand to be a problem with serialization.

I have pinpointed the problem to one specific line, a public multidimensional int array. If i change the 2d array to a 1d array, it works fine, but a 2d array is preferred for my application. As i am still learning, i would like to know specifically why this happens.

My question is, why wont the 2d array save into the settings? is it a problem of serialization? How can i implement this correctly?

```
public class AsmbLine 
{

    public int linenumber { get; set; }
    public Ticket[] ticketlist { get; set; }
    public string[] platesizes { get; set; }
    public string[] platetypes { get; set; }
    public string[] platecounts { get; set; }
    public int[,] cellidsallowed { get; set; } // This Line is the problem

    //public int[] cellidsallowed { get; set; } //uncomment these two lines to fix
    //public int[] cellidsallowedtypes { get; set; } // uncomment these two lines to fix
```

Cheers

** Edit **

Here is how i access / save my settings. i find when using custom classes that its easiest to use a seperate bool to flag if the settings is initialized for the first time start-up

```
private void asmbinitializedcheckandload()
    {
            bool temp = false;
            temp = Properties.Settings.Default.Asmbarrayinitialized;
            if (temp == false) // if this is false, then we are running for the first time
            {
                Optimo20.Properties.Settings.Default.alines = new AsmbLine[maxlines]; //create new instance of alines[]

                Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); // save

                for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.alines.Length; i++)
                {
                    Optimo20.Properties.Settings.Default.alines[i] = new AsmbLine(); // initialize each member of alines


                }    
                Properties.Settings.Default.Asmbarrayinitialized = true; // set the flag to true, setting is initialized
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); // save
             }

        alinearray = Optimo20.Properties.Settings.Default.alines; // load settings data into local array.


    }
```

Comment: Since you are learning this site would be perfect for you on how to setup what you need [dontetperls 2D array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array)

Comment: Thanks. Dotnetperls has been a huge source of help for me already!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change your code to this..? this should Compile

```
public class AsmbLine 
{
    public int linenumber { get; set; }
    public Ticket[] ticketlist { get; set; }
    public string[] platesizes { get; set; }
    public string[] platetypes { get; set; }
    public string[] platecounts { get; set; }
    //public int[] cellidsallowed { get; set; } //uncomment these two lines to fix
    private int[,] cellidsallowed;  

    public int[,] Cellidsallowed         
    {   get { return cellidsallowed; } 
        set { cellidsallowed = value; }         
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to comment/uncomment everything to switch it back over. Unfortunately it still did not work with the same error of not saving to the settings properly.

Comment: based on what you have posted and what I have tried to simplify for you.. you need to show more code.. where is the `save settings` procedure...?

Comment: Sure thing. added update above. i basically just use the properties.settings.default.save() function. other settings get saved but that one does not, and its definitely because of that int[,] thing.

Comment: what file are you looking at to see if the changes have persisted can you post the file location ? I wonder if you are looking at the wrong file

Comment: I actually dont look at a file per say. when i re-run the program and try to load the value, it just loads null for the class that i saved, while the bool flag loads "true" because i set it to that the first time (default value is false).
i check it on this line : alinearray = Optimo20....

Comment: does it actually go into the code after if(temp==false) don't you mean if(temp!=false){} correct my assumptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59609/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-metinoheat).